# Variables names starting with env

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am working with Jenkins and some variables that we use are named with env. at the beginning, e.g. env.JOB or env.CRED_USER. Why is it so? What does this "env." offer to the naming? Short question, would be thankful for short explanation :).

Comment: Consider posting short code showing where it's being used in the pipeline/job file.